# How long must you benefit from shabbos candles

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting

For example if a woman lights candles and wants to go somewhere. How long should she sit in the glow of the candles and benefit from them to be considered benefiting for Oneg shabbos. The ideal is to light where you eat. What are the exact halachic parameters and minimums?

Comment: I don't see where this is answered in the duplicate, except by disputing the premise.